# Cocoapods documentation

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to learn how to use Cocoapods but [the official guides](https://guides.cocoapods.org) seem very sparse. For example, I see commands like `File.expand_path`, `unless`, `match`, `strip` being used in other people's Podfiles, or for example I see this in a typical Flutter Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I'd love to learn how this works but none of it seems to be really explained anywhere in the official guide (for example, the word `pods_project` literally does not exist on guides.cocoapods.org). Am I missing something? Can anyone point me to any proper docs?

Comment: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods then https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/Installer checks for `pods_project` property, etc. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod%2FInstaller:pods_project It's not easy imho if you don't speak Ruby.